# Report error, value cannot be null

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, reportviewer, reportparameter

I am stymied by the above error.

I have a report with a parameter called loc.

The intended purpose of the report is to allow users to select a location from the dropdownlist and then records associated with that location are displayed to the users.

The dropdownlist is getting populated with values just fine.

However, when I select a location from the dropdownlist, I get an error that says:

**Value cannot be null. Parameter name: reportParameters**

Everything works fine when I pass a value as textbox but not as dropdown.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Below are relevant code. Please forgive me in advance for posting a lot of code.

```
 '---Dropdownlist control
 <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlLoc" Font-Names="Calibri" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1" Style="margin: 0 auto; width:300px;">
             <table>
                 <tr>
                     <td>
                         <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblLoc" Text="Location: " />
                     </td>
                     <td>
                         <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddLoc" DataSourceID="dslocator6" AutoPostBack="True">

                         </asp:DropDownList>
                     </td>
                 </tr>
             </table>
          </asp:Panel

 --Report viewer control
   <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" AsyncRendering="true" SizeToReportContent="true" Font-Names="Arial" 
        Height="675px" Width="750px">
        <LocalReport EnableExternalImages="true" ReportPath=""> 
        </LocalReport> 
    </rsweb:ReportViewer></center>
     <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="LOC" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetData" TypeName="ManageReportsTableAdapters.searchBylocationsTableAdapter">
      <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddLoc" Name="Location" DefaultValue=" " />
      </SelectParameters>
     </asp:ObjectDataSource> 


           --This code populates the ddLoc dropdownlist
               Protected Sub btnLoc_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnLoc.Click
               ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = ""
               pnlLoc.Visible = True
               which.Value = "P"
               dslocator6.SelectCommand = "SELECT location FROM Locations ORDER BY [location]"
               ddLoc.DataTextField = "location"
               ddLoc.DataValueField = "location"
              End Sub

           'Define report parameter
           Dim params(0) As ReportParameter


            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("locs", LOC.ID))
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "locations.rdlc"
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh()

            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ddLoc.SelectedValue) Then
                params(0) = New ReportParameter("loc", ddLoc.SelectedValue)
            Else
                params(0) = New ReportParameter("loc", sel, False)
            End If
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(params) '<-- error points to this line
```

Comment: In the code above, you check ddLoc.SelectedValue for string empty or null but what about the parameter "sel" which you use in the else statement? what value does that variable has?

Comment: @Ricardo, hi. sorry I had a hard time getting back in.. Slow internet I suppose.

I put a breakpoint on that line but still got same error.

Even a response.end() debug would not get me past that error.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error and the problem was me setting an extra index in my array

```
Dim params(2) As ReportParameter
params(0) = New ReportParameter("SignatureImg", "SomeBase64StringHere")
params(1) = New ReportParameter("SignatureImgMimeType", "image/png")
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(params)
```

Because of I defined my array like this Dim params(2) As ReportParameter and i was just adding values for the first two index the value on index 3 was null and it was creating the problem.

The solution was just defined the array like this Dim params(1) As ReportParameter.